# dropdown menu sorting with query

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli, drop-down-menu

im sure this would be a simple fix but im lost as to where to place the sort function in this.

```
 <select class="form-control" name="unit"><option></option>
 <?php
    $query=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM units") or die(mysqli_error($db));
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {
    if(!in_array($row["id"], $units)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"><?php echo $row["unitsn"];?></option>
```

it imports all the data i want just looks to be sorted as old on top new on bottom. i would like it ascending in alphabetic order if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add ordering to your MySQL query, like so:

```
$query=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM units ORDER BY unitsn DESC") or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

For fields that are strings in MySQL, the default ordering method is alphabetical.